# How to register views automatically in Xamarin.Forms with Prism

Tags: c#, xamarin, unity-container, xamarin.forms, prism-6

In Xamarin.Forms with Prism and Unity, is there a way to register all the views that are subject to navigation without specifying them explicitly?

The sample project provided by Prism, has a function RegisterTypes in the App.xaml.cs that has the following line :

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
```

I expect this to be much larger at some point of developping the application.

I am no expert of Unity, but I was trying some ways with the DependencyService, or the IUnityContainer, without any success.

```
Container.Registrations.Where(cm => cm.RegisteredType == typeof (IView));
Container.ResolveAll<IView>();
DependencyService.Get<IEnumerable<IView>>();
```

So how would I go about registering all the views (or at least a subset of the views, that for example, implements a given interface) for navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a tiny bit of reflections you could register all types of the core assembly that inherit from `Page`.

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate("MainPage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        RegisterAllPages();
    }

    private void RegisterAllPages()
    {
        var pageBaseTypeInfo = typeof(Page).GetTypeInfo();
        var types = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.DefinedTypes;
        var pageTypeInfos = types
                        .Where(x => x.IsClass && pageBaseTypeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(x));

        foreach (var page in pageTypeInfos)
        {
            // the next two lines do what RegisterTypeForNavigation does
            Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), page.AsType(), page.Name);
            PageNavigationRegistry.Register(page.Name, page.AsType());
        }
    }
}
```